# Scraping Excel Macros

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

estoy intentando de hacer scraping en la siguiente pagina https://sns.ift.org.mx:8081/sns-frontend/consulta-numeracion/numeracion-geografica.xhtml sobre el campo "Número Nacional". he estado intentando con el siguiente mas se me presentaron problemas ya que el sitio utiliza JS para deshabilitar el botón de consulta hasta que no se ingrese un valor de 10 dígitos. E logrado insertar un valor en el input mas el sitio no detecta la entrada de los dígitos, espero me puedan ayudar a solucionarlo, dejo el código.

```
Sub SNS()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate "https://sns.ift.org.mx:8081/sns-frontend/consulta-numeracion/numeracion-geografica.xhtml"

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

     objIE.document.getElementById("FORM_myform:TXT_NationalNumber").value = "NUMERO_de_Telefono_a_Consultar"
     objIE.document.getElementById("FORM_myform:BTN_publicSearch").onclick


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes reemplazar

```
 objIE.document.getElementById("FORM_myform:TXT_NationalNumber").value = "NUMERO_de_Telefono_a_Consultar"
```

Por

```
objIE.document.getElementById("FORM_myform:TXT_NationalNumber")(0).value = "NUMERO_de_Telefono_a_Consultar"
```

Si es el único nombre `name="FORM_myform:TXT_NationalNumber"`, `(0)` debería trabajar si no puedes probar con `(1)`o con la posición que corresponda.